# What program starts dbus-daemon?

Tags: session, dbus

What program starts the per user session dbus-daemon process in GNOME 2 and GNOME 3 (presumably via dbus-launch)?  I would like to know because I would like to add a directory to the list of directories that dbus-daemon checks for .service files.

(Obviously if it's a sh program, "sh" isn't the answer I'm looking for ;-)

How could I have answered this question for myself efficiently?  What documentation is there on desktop and session startup?

Comment: So, no luck still?

Comment: In the future use `pstree` and `pstree -p` to see the actual PIDs

Comment: Pithikos: per my comment on your answer, those commands don't help if the process has already been reparented to init, as was the case here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The login manager starts dbus via the Xsession scripts directory. If the `use-session-dbus` option is set for the Xsession, then the dbus Xsession script is loaded, and it runs `dbus-launch --exit-with-session $session_command`.

Comment: So if dbus-launch starts the session manager, then the session manager is not the program that starts dbus-launch, so that doesn't appear to answer the question?

Comment: As it happens the reason that I want to add a directory that is checked for .service files is that I'm doing a non-root install.  So I can't create session-local.conf.  I can always start a second dbus-daemon, but I'd like to avoid that if possible (partly for parsimony, partly because it seems dbus-launch processes get left behind after the program that it ran exited, so it's not easy to write a well-behaving shell alias that runs a program using dbus-launch).

Comment: Why do you need to install a .service file at all? Do you actually need to use the activation feature of dbus? Your question doesn't really say what you're trying to do exactly; which would probably be easier to answer, as dbus-daemon/dbus-launch could get started a large number of different ways, depending on what session the user is running.

Comment: I didn't state what I was trying to do because I can already do it (I was trying to run a local installation of hamster, a time-tacking program; I can do that by running hamster using dbus-launch as a prefix command).  I defend my right as a geek to genuinely want to know the answer to exactly the question I asked :-)

Comment: You asked 3 questions. Pick one. :)

Comment: The first one: What program starts dbus-daemon?

Comment: Looks like one of dobey's edits changed the answer to answer the question: thanks dobey! (either that or I misread it the first time -- though don't think I did that).  Here is the file with the code that runs dbus-launch: /etc/X11/Xsession.d/75dbus_dbus-launch (and I assume some X code is responsible for running that code, which is in turn run by lightdm or gdm)

Answer (score 2):

Starting of the majority of tasks and services during boot including Dbus daemon is handled by [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

Dbus daemon is not started per user session but on mounting the last [local filesystem](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#local-filesystems). Upstart job configuration handling starting/stopping/monitoring of Dbus daemon can be found in `/etc/init/dbus.conf`.

You can use [user job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#user-job) to start Hamster on [graphical login](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-when-a-user-logs-in-graphically-ubuntu-specific).

Comment: I checked this as accepted answer, then realised that that script starts the "system" dbus-daemon (with argument --system).  I hear what you say about not being started per  user session, but then why do I have two dbus-daemon processes (in fact, three, but the third one looks less interesting)?  One looks like the one started by that init file, the other has argument --session (amongst other arguments) instead of argument --system

Comment: That will be specific to your setup. Your question was as per comment 5: What program starts dbus-daemon? More information on starting per session message buss you can find [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dbus-launch.1.html).

Comment: Hi schkovich.  That comment was to help out dobey, who seemed unsure whether my "how could I have answered this for myself" was a further two questions rather than, as it was, an invitation/reminder to "teach a man to fish".  If you take a look at the original question, you'll see what it's about in more detail: explicitly session, not system.  By the way, thanks for your answer: I was happy to upvote it as useful info, even if not directly answering my question.

Comment: The most important is that you got the answer to your question and that each of us has learned a bit more about Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score -1):

I will disagree with dobey. The best thing to do is to learn how to find it for yourself.

List all processes and their PID tree structure:

```
pstree
init─┬─ModemManager───2*[{ModemManager}]
     ├─NetworkManager─┬─2*[dhclient]
     │                ├─dnsmasq
     │                └─3*[{NetworkManager}]
     ├─accounts-daemon───2*[{accounts-daemon}]
     ├─acpid
     ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
     ├─bluetoothd
     ├─colord───2*[{colord}]
     ├─cron
     ├─cups-browsed
     ├─cupsd
     ├─dbus-daemon
....
```

So dbus-daemon is started by `init`. However notice that there is more than one dbus-daemon running.

```
manos@box:~$ ps aux | grep dbus-daemon
message+   845  0.0  0.0  40668  2620 ?        Ss   10:48   0:03 dbus-daemon --system --fork
manos     2480  0.0  0.0  40248  2428 ?        Ss   10:48   0:01 dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-o3GMKn9JC1
manos     2569  0.0  0.0  39248  2004 ?        S    10:48   0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
```

There are namely (at least) two instances of dbus-daemon running. One is started by init and it's system wide and the other is started for the user when he logged in. Watching the full PID tree structure (with `pstree`) you can visually locate exactly which process started the second instance.

Comment: Processes whose parent has exited are reparented to init by the kernel.  So children of init are in fact not normally directly started by that process.  In this case, dbus-daemon is not -- see dobey's answer

Comment: @CroadLangshan hmm didn't think about that. Thanks for the input